# How to fetch API data from Axios inside the getServerSideProps function in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, next.js

I'm building an App with Next.js, and I need to connect to specific API routes (set up with [API Platform](https://api-platform.com)) and populate pages with the route's responses.

The API is working fine, but no matter how I try to implement my Axios call inside the `getServerSideProps`, I always get the same error, `ECONNREFUSED`, from my Node stack.

I tried to get the data from `useEffect()` and it's working fine, but I would like to know if there's a way to call it directly in `getServerSideProps`.

I'm using a Node container for Docker, and the routes are authenticated through a JWT Token (stored in the session and the client cookies for the server-side connection)

Here are is my code:

`pages/accounts.js`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookies = new Cookies(context.req.headers.cookie)
  const adminToken = cookies.get('jwtToken')

  const res = await getAllAccounts(adminToken)

  return {
    props: {
      testdata: ''
    },
  }
}
```

`lib/accounts.js`:

```js
import service from '../service'

export const getAllAccounts = async (adminToken) => {
  const res = service({ jwtToken : adminToken }).get(`/accounts`).then((response) => {
  
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.dir(error)
  })
}
```

HTTP wrapper:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import mockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const service = ({ jwtToken = null, store = null, mockURL = null, mockResponse = null, multipart = false } = {}) => {
  const options = {};

  options.baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + '/api';

  if(multipart === true) {
    options.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  } else {
    options.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
      accept: 'application/ld+json'
    }
  }

  const instance = axios.create(options);

  instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
  }, error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  })

  if (mockURL !== null && mockResponse !== null) {
    let mock = new mockAdapter(instance);
    mock.onAny(mockURL).reply(200, mockResponse)
  }

  return instance;
};

export default service;
```

Through the error dump in the node stack, I managed to see that the request headers are correct, and the JWT correctly passed through.

Comment: Does the rest of the URL get added somewhere? A relative URL won't work from the server since it has no awareness of what domain it's on like a browser does.

Comment: Hi ! I added a .env.local file to specify the API URL (with process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL). It specifies NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:8001 and I can see the url is correct in the error stack in the node container... 
I also attempted to do the axios call directly in the getServerSideProps, with the full url string, still the same result..
Do you suggest I do otherwise ?
Thanks !

Comment: As long as it's getting the full URL, I don't have another suggestion. It was just something worth checking. I see that part in the code you provided now, so that was my mistake.

Comment: [`getStaticProps`'s context](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) does not have access to `req` (nor headers/cookies) as it runs on the server at build-time. Have you tried using `getServerSideProps` instead?

Comment: Hi ! Yes I'm so sorry, I've put the wrong function in my post. I initially tried to make things work with getServerSideProps, I will immediatly edit my post.
To answer your question, same problem with getServerSideProps

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible repo or codesandbox link ?

Answer (score 11):

Do not use Axios. Just use `fetch()`.

Next.js polyfills `fetch()` by default on both the client and server, so you can just use it:

> In addition to `fetch()` on the client-side, Next.js polyfills `fetch()` in the Node.js environment. You can use `fetch()` in your server code (such as `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`) without using polyfills such as `isomorphic-unfetch` or `node-fetch`.

[Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#server-side-polyfills).

Answer (score 3):

getServerSideProps works well with axios if we return `response.data`

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { brandName } = params as IParams;
  const brandData = await $host.get(`api/brand/${brandName}`).then(response => response.data);

  return {
    props: {
      brand: brandData,
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your async method does not return a promise.

```
import service from '../service'

export const getAllAccounts = async (adminToken) => {
  const res = service({ jwtToken : adminToken }).get(`/accounts`);
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my NextJS begining I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/2zRHlqc0_yw?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g9gP2onazU5-2M-AzA8eBw) , and I changed fetch to axios in this way:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
   const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
   const data = await res.json();

   const paths = data.map((ninja) => {
     return {
       params: { id: ninja.id.toString() },
     };
   });

   return {
     paths,
     fallback: false,
   };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
   const id = context.params.id;
   const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);
   const data = await res.json();

   return {
     props: { ninja: data },
   };
};
```

I applied the change using useEffect()

```
useEffect(() => {
    // const data = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);
    // const res = await data.json();
    // setninja(res);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);

      setninja(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log(data);
  }, []);
```

I hope this info will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I Used Axios in getServerSideProps without any problems.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async({
  params,
  res
}) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/test`);
    return {
      props: {
        data: response.data
      },
    }
  } catch {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    return {
      props: {}
    };
  }
};
```